# Sprite image not appearing on matter.js

Tags: javascript, html, matter.js

I am trying to replace the standard `circle body` with an image sprite but it isn't showing the image.

```js
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
  Render = Matter.Render,
  World = Matter.World,
  Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
  Body = Matter.Body,
  Constraint = Matter.Constraint,
  Vector = Matter.Vector,
  Events = Matter.Events,
  Mouse = Matter.Mouse,
  MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;

// create an engine
var engine = Engine.create();

engine.world.gravity.y = 0; // gravity not needed in this app

// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine
});

var ball_0 = Bodies.circle(100, 100, 11, {
  density: 0.04,
  frictionAir: 0.06,
  restitution: 0.8,
  friction: 0.01,
  render: {
    sprite: {
      texture: 'images/white.png',
      xScale: 20,
      yScale: 20
    }
  }
});

// add all of the bodies to the world
World.add(engine.world, ball_0);

// run the engine
Engine.run(engine);

// run the renderer
Render.run(render);
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/releases/download/0.10.0/matter.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your `Render.create(...)` can you add the `options: {wireframes: false}` attribute?

Comment: That did the job, must have missed it in the docs. ty.

Comment: I'm going to add an answer in case someone else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are drawing everything in wireframe.  Change your `Render.create()` call to turn off wireframes with `options: {wireframes: false}`:

```
// create a renderer
var render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine,
  options: {wireframes: false}
});
```

Comment: I noticed that the wiki does cover this - https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/wiki/Rendering

Answer (score 2):

**Setting `wireframes: false` is half the answer, you also need to first load the image before setting it as texture**

You must load the Image before setting it as Texture otherwise you will get error

> HTMLImageElement is in "broken" state

For me this issue end up printing 900+ error messages which crashed my sandbox.

**Solution**: I created a simple Image loader:

```
const loadImage = (url, onSuccess, onError) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
    onSuccess(img.src);
  };
  img.onerror = onError();
  img.src = url;
};
```

And later I used that loader to load the texture. Once texture is loaded you can set it as texture for your Body objects.

```
 loadImage(
      "./assets/blue.jpg",
      url => {
        console.log("Success");
        World.add(world, [
          Bodies.circle(340, 340, 100, {
            density: 0.0005,
            frictionAir: 0.06,
            restitution: 0.3,
            friction: 0.01,
            render: {
              sprite: {
                texture: url // set texture here
              }
            }
          })
        ]);
      },
      () => {
        console.log("Error  Loading ");
      }
    );
```

**Important**: before calling `Renderer.run()` you must disable wireframes

```
// create renderer
var render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    wireframes: false, // disable Wireframe
  }
});

Render.run(render);
```

Comment: I also had the error spam to happen, but it was due to incorrect url, no preloading was needed to fix

Comment: This ended up being my issue too. I was incorrectly using a relative path :/